# Custom name for a count metric prometheus

Tags: prometheus, spring-webflux, spring-micrometer

i have an endpoint in a webflux application and i want to build a metric to count how many times this endpoint is called with which parameters and then this metric will be exposed for prometheus.
This is how i done to log the metric:

```
    public <T> Mono<T> logMetric(Mono<T> mono, Shop shop) {
        return mono
            .name("shop_count")
            .tag("level", findLevel(shop))
            .tag("inland", isInland(shop))
            .tap(Micrometer.observation(observationRegistry));
    }
```

There i added a name for my mono and tag it with some parameters which i want to log.

This is what i get when call /actuator/prometheus endpoint:

[image: result]

It's working fine that I can see now the count metric with the parameters i added, and everytime when i call the endpoint the count metric increases.

But my question is how can i rename the metric name from "shop_count_seconds_count" to only "shop_count". I have set the name for the mono to only "shop_count" but not sure where the suffix "seconds_count" is coming from and how can i remove it. Does anyone have an idea? Thank you

i tried to google but no result sofar